# Use an FirebaseAnimatedList as Sliver

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I was wondering how a `FirebaseAnimatedList` can be used within a `CustomScrollView` as a Sliver?
What I'm looking for is a combination of both `SliverAnimatedList` and `FirebaseAnimatedList`.